# Youtube iFrame Embedded Video Tracking - Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I would like to track Youtube iFrame embedded video through GTM. 
Now its working fine for me in normal [GA implementation method](http://vinonsearch.com/youtubeaug3.html).

I tried to use the [same code](http://vinonsearch.com/vinoyoutube.js) in GTM using custom HTML tag. But, its not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this before your GTM container code:

```
<!-- GA safeguard declare _gaq -->
<script>
   var _gaq = [];
</script>
```

That should allow GA events to pass into/through GTM and into GA.